# Suitescript saved search returning duplicate values

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I have a record with a sublist, and every item of that sublist is a record that has another sublist. What I want is, for every itemA get all the sublist of every itemA sublist. Like this

```
Bill of Lading
  ->FulfillmentA
      ->Item123
      ->Item124
      ->Item125
  ->FulfillmentB
      ->Item224
      ->Item226
      ->Item227
```

I created a saved search,but the search returns duplicated values, aswell as empty ones, I read about mainline so I used that, but when _I do that, some records are missing.

With mainline False

```
new nlobjSearchFilter('mainline', null, 'is', 'F')
```

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiUgf.png)

With mainline True

```
new nlobjSearchFilter('mainline', null, 'is', 'T')
```

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1w0z.png)

Here is the full code:

```
    var lines= record.getLineItemCount('recmachcustrecord_id_billoflading');
    var afulfill = []; 

    for(var i = 1; i <= lines; i++){
        afulfill.push(record.getLineItemValue('recmachcustrecord_id_billoflading', 'custrecord_fulfillment', i));
    }

    if(afulfill != null && afulfill.length>0){
        var filters = [ 
            new nlobjSearchFilter('internalid', null, 'anyof', afulfill), 
            new nlobjSearchFilter('mainline', null, 'is', 'T'),

            ];
        var columns = [new nlobjSearchColumn('item')];
        var searchresult = nlapiSearchRecord('itemfulfillment', null, filters, columns);
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < searchresult.length; i++){
        var search = searchresult[ i ];
        htmlCode += "<p>" + JSON.stringify(search) + "</p>";
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I want only the `item` lines of a transaction, I typically build my search with the following filters:

- `Main Line is false`
- `COGS Line is false`
- `Shipping Line is false`
- `Tax Line is false`

As you can see, there are far more sublists that show up in transaction results than just the item sublist, so you need to filter out the others (tax, shipping, COGS). You could also add a filter like `Item is not empty` as well to see how that impacts your results.